# Read news feed from non-friends

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Is it possible with the Facebook API to get a users news feed posts if they aren't your friend on Facebook?

My scenario is something like this: In my iOS app I'd like for Person A to be able read Person B's feed if say Person B allows permissions for the app do to so and if both users have the app installed.

Is this sort of thing supported or do both people have to friends on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. But you should be able to do that through your app. That is store Person B's feed and post it on Person A's feed as app.

Comment: So you're saying I'd have to store my own copy of each persons feed so it can be displayed to each other? I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this and could just generate the feeds dynamically instead of storing it in a database.

Comment: That's the only way i can think of at the moment.